# React NPM Error - code ERESOLVE, ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-sheets, npm, npm-install

In my React Native app, when I try to install `npm i google-spreadsheet --save` I get the below error.

How can I fix it?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"18.1.0" from react-native@0.70.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!     peerOptional react-native@">=0.59" from react-redux@8.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!       react-redux@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!     react-native@"0.70.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0" from react-redux@8.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!     react-redux@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (react-shallow-renderer, react-test-renderer, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peerOptional react-dom@"^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0" from react-redux@8.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!     react-redux@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peerOptional react-dom@"^16.8 || ^17.0 || ^18.0" from react-redux@8.0.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!       react-redux@"^8.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\harry\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\harry\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-06T05_01_54_912Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Did you try npm i google-spreadsheet --legacy-peer-deps ?

Comment: @PMArtz I tried with `yarn install` and it seems it has fixed the version problem.

Comment: So you ignored the warning? You win developer of the day.